# How to OPEN Sonarqube Server on Heroku ( -> buildpack https://github.com/NayaraCaetano/heroku-buildpack-sonarqube.git)

Tags: heroku, sonarqube

**What worked so far:** I installed sonarqube locally with mvn sonar:sonar I get the results on localhost:9000. 
Now I want to do the same thing for our app that is hosted on heroku. I could successfully install the buildpack from NayaraCaetano with

```
    heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/ https://github.com/NayaraCaetano/heroku-buildpack-sonarqube.git/heroku-buildpack-sonarqube.git  -a ourAppName
```

On heroku I saw that the buildpack was added.

**Not working / unclear** 
So how am I now able to open the sonarqube findings from heroku, I didn't find any documentation on this but not shure if I am missing the point of what this buildpack is supposed to do

Answer (score 0):

In the end we were able to use sonarcloud.io. Since our heroku app was anyway connected to github we just created an account at sonarcloud that was connected to our master branch. 
It's not really the solution i hoped for, but it meet our goal to constantly monitor our code coverage on every commit to the master branch.